# Node location of meshgrid in Pygimli.meshtool

Tags: python, mesh, modeling, differential-equations, finite-element-analysis

I have designed a mesh and solved differential equation on every node of the mesh. I have got the solution at each node with node number,
e.g. node1. 72.36 mV,
node2. 89.58 mV,
node3. 65.68 mV, and so on.....
The mesh is designed in a 2d space. I want to know the (x,y) location of each node number. How can I do that?

(N.B.- I have experimented on how the meshtool assign node number, I got that it chooses the next node number using some shortest distance type algorithm)

Comment: If you expect to receive some help, please show some of your code. The best would be a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the `x()` and `y()` methods on the node. Check out the [tutorials](https://www.pygimli.org/_tutorials_auto/index.html).

[image]